# Copy file from Server A to Server B

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I have requirement to copy files from Server A to Server B
And then move the copied files Server A to Archive folder

I have written the script, but it takes the directory name differently.
Copying file from Server A to Server B is working, but moving file to Archive folder is failing

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="tempusr"
dir_origin="/data"
dir_destination="/export/home/tempusr/data"
Ip="123.456.789"

echo $dir_origin

echo "Uploading files to remote server...."
dt=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
for file in /data/*.xml
do
    name=${file%.*}
    echo "Name is: "${name}
    echo "File is: "/data/$file
    echo "Coping files from Server A to Server B"
    scp -rC $file $username@$Ip:$dir_destination
    echo "New File is: " /data/processed/${name}_${dt}.xml
    echo "Moving files from Server A /data to /data/processed and appending timestamp before file type"
    mv $file /data/processed/${name}_${dt}.xml
done
echo "File upload to remote server completed! ;)"
```

Output I am getting is:
ISSUE: If you check the line File is:
its taking path as "/data//data/" but it need path as just /data/.
I am not getting, where I am wrong.

```
./transfer.sh
/data
Uploading files to remote server....
Name is: /data/1552653_123510007_1316325
File is: /data//data/1552653_123510007_1316325.xml
SERVERB password:
1552653_123510007_1316325.xml 100% 2204 1.6MB/s 00:00
New File is: /data/processed//data/1552653_123510007_1316325_20230914002942.xml
mv: cannot move '/data/1552653_123510007_1316325.xml' to '/data/processed//data/1552653_123510007_1316325_20230914002942.xml': No such file or directory.
```

Also, it asks for password every time and on this system `sshpass` and run `apt install sshpass`.
So is there any other way, where I can pass password directly in `scp` command or such that I don't need to enter password every time.

Comment: Use ssh keys to enable login without password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can clearly be seen in your very first line of output,

> ```
> Name is: /data/1552653_123510007_1316325
> ```

Everywhere you use `$name` you will be including the `/data/` prefix.

So to fix this, either strip the prefix from `$name` or stop reincluding `/data` in your paths. Here's one approach:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
username="tempusr"
origin="/data"
backup="/data/processed"
destination="/export/home/tempusr/data"
ip="203.0.113.1"

dt=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

echo "Uploading files to remote server..."
for file in "$origin"/*.xml
do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue    # In case there are no files to copy

    name=${file%.*}               # Strip extension
    name=${name##*/}              # Strip leading path
    save="${name}_$dt.xml"        # Backup filename with datetime suffix

    echo "Name is: $name"
    echo "File is: $file"

    echo "Copying file from Server A to Server B"
    scp -C -- "$file" "$username@$ip:$destination"

    echo "New file is: $backup/$save"
    echo "Moving file from Server A $origin to $backup and appending timestamp before file type"
    mv -f -- "$file" "$backup/$save"
done
echo 'File upload to remote server completed! ;)'
```

You can use `ssh` public key certificates to avoid entering a password each time. This is well documented but the gist of it is as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519      # Take defaults, do not overwrite an existing key
ssh-copy-id username@ip    # Replace username@ip to match your script values
```

If `ed25519` is not recognised you can try `rsa` instead, but make sure `ssh-copy-id` copies the correct public key.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I got the script working as below
But now I have another query
I have 1.5 milion files in single directory on Server A and I have a script which will move these to Server B. Currently my script moves all the files at one go.

I am looking for a process where I can move files in chunk. For Example: Moving 10000 files at each time That means when I run the script, it will first move 10000 files, then sleep for few minutes, then move the next 10000 files and so on. All files are of 3KB size.

Comment: @user3792741 "_I have another query_" - you can ask another question. If it's a follow-on from this question you may find it helpful to others to include a reference to this one. However, one way of approaching this would be to use a counter and `break` from the loop when you've reached your maximum value

Answer (score 1):

Replace line:

```
    mv $file /data/processed/${name}_${dt}.xml
```

with

```
    mv "$file" /data/processed/"${name##*/}_${dt}.xml"
```

The `##*/` will strip of the path (everything until (including) the last slash) of the variable name. Double-quoting the variables will ensure that file names containing spaces or other shell-sensitive characters will still be processed correctly.

For your other problem, as mentioned in the comments, set up ssh public key authentication without passphrase for your private key.